# import jgrapht package into my netbeans project

Tags: netbeans, import, jgrapht

I am not knowing how to use the classes written in netbeans for one of my project . in which folder should i place the jgrapht package . will i have to write the import statement if yes then what do i write ?

Comment: you may want to add a bit more info about what you are trying to do.  And what you have done so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

say you've created a project named 'myproject'. now you want to use jgrapht package in that project. just do the following:
under 'myproject' there are four sub-directories,

1. Source Packages
2. Test Packages
3. Libraries
4. Test Libraries

'right click' on 'Libraries' directory. Now, a menu appears that offers

1. Add Project
2. Add Library
3. Add jar/folder
4. Properties

select Add jar/folder. Now just locate where is your "jgrapht-jdk1.6.jar" file.

hope it helps